# Find height of a sphere, given it forms a tangent with a plane defined by a point and normal, and the X and Z coordinates of the sphere are known.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, 3d, spheres

I'm currently making a game and have run into a problem I'm not quite sure how to solve, I'll try to lay it out as a maths question. None of the values are fixed, so I'm looking for an equation that solves the below question:

A plane lies on the position vector `p0` `<x0, y0, z0>` and has a normal unit vector `n` `<a, b, c>`.

Given a sphere with a radius of `R` forms a tangent with the plane at an unknown position vector `t` `<tx, ty, tz>`:

Find the highest height of the center of a sphere, when the sphere is located at the position vector `s` `<sx, sy, sz>`, and `sx` and `sz` are known values, but `sy` is not.

The known vectors are `p0`, `n`, and the other known values are `sx`, `sz`, and `R`. The position vector `t` is unknown, and the height of the sphere `sy` is also unknown. Should it be necessary, another point on the plane `p1` `<x1, y1, z1>` can be provided.

In my case, the Y axis is the up axis, the Z axis is the forward axis, and the X axis is the right axis.

I wanted to essentially do something similar to what is shown in this video, but in my case I know the length of the vector but not the positions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWMTTRJ0l4w

Here is 2d visualisation of the problem:
[image: Sphere and plane]

I was only able to find the positions due to trial and error, but these were approximately correct.

Here is what I do know:
The vector `t` to `s` will have the same direction as the normal vector, but with the magnitude being equal to R. It could then be defined as `Rn`, given that `n` is a unit vector.
Given that, the vector could be defined as a translation of the vector `Rn` along the plane.

Beyond this point, I am a little confused, so any help would be appreciated.
I would prefer to avoid cartesian form, and values can be stored in variables at later dates if necessary.
I have v1:Dot(v2) and v1:Cross(v2) methods available to me, and I expect this probably will use the dot product at some point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

$$R, \ \
\cases{
\vec p_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)\\
\vec n = (n_x,n_y,n_z)\\
\vec s = (s_x,u,s_z)\\
}
$$

determine $\vec t=(t_x,t_y,t_z),\ u,\ \lambda$ such that

$$
\cases{
(\vec t-\vec p_0)\cdot \vec n = 0\\
\|\vec t - \vec s\|^2 = R^2\\
\vec t-\vec s = \lambda \vec n
}
$$

five equations and five unknowns $t_x,t_y,t_z,u,\lambda$.

NOTE

One solution is

$$
\cases{
t_x = s_x + \frac{R n_x}{\|\vec n\|}\\
t_y = \frac{1}{n_y}\left(n_x(x_0-s_x)+n_y y_0+n_z(z_0-s_z)-\frac{(n_x^2+n_y^2)R}{\|\vec n\|}\right)\\
t_z = s_z + \frac{R n_z}{\|\vec n\|}\\
u = \frac{1}{n_y}\left(n_x(x_0-s_x)+n_yy_0+n_z(z_0-s_z)-\|\vec n\|R\right)\\
\lambda = \frac{R}{\|\vec n\|}
}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The center of the sphere lies on the line

$ C(t) = (s_x, 0, s_z) + t (0, 1, 0) = (s_x, t, s_z) $

We want the distance of a point on this line to be equal to the known given value of $R$ (the radius of the sphere).  The formula for the signed distance is

$ d =  \hat{n} \cdot ( C(t) - p_0)  $

where $\hat{n}$ is the normalized normal vector of the plane.

Equating $d$ to $R$ results in the center of the sphere that on the side of the plane pointed to by $\hat{n}$, while setting $d$ to $(-R)$ gives the center of the sphere that is on the opposite side as the one pointed to by $\hat{n}$.

Now the tangency point is given by

$ T = C - d \hat{n} $

where $d$ can be $+R$ or $-R$, but $C$ is different between these two cases.

Now the height of the sphere is

$ h = C_z + R $

Answer (score 0):

It took some thinking, but I managed to find a solution to finding `sy`.

Essentially, the length of the vector between `t` and `s`, which I will call vector R can be defined using:

`abs|n ⋅ (s - p0)|`.

Since the length of the vector is already known, this allows us to set up an equation such that:

`R = abs|n · (s - p0)|`

Then, expanding:

`R = abs|<nx, ny, nz> · <sx - x0, sy - y0, sz - z0>|`

`R = abs|nx(sx - x0) + ny(sy - y0) + nz(sz - z0)|`

`R = abs|nx·sx + ny·sy + nz·sz - nx·x0 - ny·y0 - nz·z0|`

Given that it is absolute, that means that it could be `+R` or `-R`.

`R = nx·sx + ny·sy + nz·sz - nx·x0 - ny·y0 - nz·z0`

OR

`-R = nx·sx + ny·sy + nz·sz - nx·x0 - ny·y0 - nz·z0`

First I will re-arrange the positive, keeping in mind there is also a negative solution.

`ny·sy = R - nx·sx - nz·sz + nx·x0 + ny·y0 + nz·z0`

Dividing by Y:

`sy = ((R - nx·sx - nz·sz + nx·x0 + nz·z0) / ny) + y0`

Remembering there is also `-R` this gives us the two solutions:

`sy1 =  ((R - nx·sx - nz·sz + nx·x0 + nz·z0) / ny) + y0`

`sy2 = ((-R - nx·sx - nz·sz + nx·x0 + nz·z0) / ny) + y0`

Then, selecting the maximum of each:

`sy = math.max(sy1, sy2)`

Which then gives us our vector `S` `<sx, sy, sz>`

The tangent point can then be calculated by taking away `Rn` from our calculated `S` vector.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My answer could literally not be any clearer, given I am answering my own question